# How can I read a dot file as a adjacency matrix in python?

Tags: python, dot

I am trying to partition a graph in a dot file using pymetis. Pymetis takes in an adjacency matrix. How do I read the dot file with a directed graph to generate a adjacency matrix which can be passed on to pymetis.part_graph() ?

dot file has a graph in this format:

```
digraph {
    a -> b[label="0.2",weight="0.2"];
    a -> c[label="0.4",weight="0.4"];
    c -> b[label="0.6",weight="0.6"];
    c -> e[label="0.6",weight="0.6"];
    e -> e[label="0.1",weight="0.1"];
    e -> b[label="0.7",weight="0.7"];
}
```

Here is the code I have so far to read the dot file:

```
import os
import dot_tools

file = open("test.dot", 'r')
text = file.read()
tree = dot_tools.parse(text)
print tree
```

output:

```
1:Graphs
3:Graph
0:digraph
0:graph_1001
1:Stmts
6:Edges
3:->
0:a
0:b
2:Attrs
2:=
0:label
0:0.2
2:=
0:weight
0:0.2
3:->
0:a
0:c
2:Attrs
2:=
0:label
0:0.4
2:=
0:weight
0:0.4
3:->
0:c
0:b
2:Attrs
2:=
0:label
0:0.6
2:=
0:weight
0:0.6
3:->
0:c
0:e
2:Attrs
2:=
0:label
0:0.6
2:=
0:weight
0:0.6
3:->
0:e
0:e
2:Attrs
2:=
0:label
0:0.1
2:=
0:weight
0:0.1
3:->
0:e
0:b
2:Attrs
2:=
0:label
0:0.7
2:=
0:weight
0:0.7
```

I want to know if there any modules to create an adjacency matrix from the directed graph in the dot file.

Comment: I suggest first to have a look on [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ I have looked at your link before posting, the link reads the dot file as a str. I am already doing that. My use case is different, please read and understand the question before you mark it as a duplicate. You need to slow down on your conclusions, SPEED does not equal accuracy.